# Llenar GridView con dos tablas anidadas

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo las siguientes dos tablas anidadas:

```
TAREAS(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
TAREA VARCHAR(50),
DETALLES VARCHAR(200),
FECHAINICIO DATETIME,
FECHAFIN DATETIME);

TRABAJADORES_TAREAS(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
TAREA INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TAREAS(ID),
TRABAJADOR INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TRABAJADORES(ID)
);

TRABAJADORES(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),
APELLIDO VARCHAR(100),
ESPECIALIDAD VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Como pueden ver pueden haber muchos trabajadores en una misma tarea y cada trabajador puede tener muchas tareas asignadas. Quiero mostrar los datos en un GridView, pero no se como hacer que se repitan los registros o existe otro control que me ayude mejor.

```
GV-TRABAJADORES-TAREAS:

ID - TAREA - DETALLES - FECHA INICIO - FECHA FIN - TRABAJADORES

1  - tarea1 - bla bla - 01-11-17     - 02-11-17  - Adan Alvarez/Beto Beltran/...
```

algo así me gustaría que se visualizara.

Comment: Buenas Luis, tienes que mostrar las pruebas que hayas hecho y que es lo que te está costando o dando problemas, sin eso nosotros no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: No se cual es la mejor manera de visualizar esa lista de trabajadores dentro del gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas relacionar las tablas mediante una unión y genear una funcion que te regrese una lista de trabajadores

podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

**generar la siguiente función tipo escalar**

```
USE [Ejemplo]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_ConcatenaMemo]    Script 
Date: 09/11/2017 12:45:44 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER function [dbo].[fn_ConcatenaMemo] (@id int)
returns varchar(50)
as 
begin
declare @memo varchar(50)
set @memo = ''
select @memo = @memo + '  '+[dbo].[TRABAJADORES].[NOMBRE] from [dbo].
[TRABAJADORES]

return (@memo)
end
```

**Ahora tienes que solo poner esta consulta**

```
    select top 1 * ,[dbo].[fn_ConcatenaMemo](1)
from [dbo].[TRABAJADORES_TAREAS] 
inner join [dbo].[TAREAS] on [dbo].[TRABAJADORES_TAREAS].[TAREA]=[dbo].[TAREAS].[ID] 
inner join [dbo].[TRABAJADORES] on [dbo].[TRABAJADORES_TAREAS].[TRABAJADOR]=[dbo].[TRABAJADORES].[ID]
where [dbo].[TAREAS].[ID]=1

select [dbo].[fn_ConcatenaMemo](1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

jeje en la consulta final solo selecciona los campos que quieras y ya, no te vaya a pasar como a mi en la foto

Comment: pongo 1 por que es la tarea 1, aparece juan y pepe por que ellos tienen la tarea 1 asiganada